# Why does MS SQL Server return results with 'LIKE' query but returns empty set using '='

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using utilizing MS SQL Server 2017. In this example, I have a table [myTable] with one entity `full name (varchar(255)`.

Inside of this table, I have one record bulk imported with the following parameters

```
(FIELDTERMINATOR = '~',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A' )
```

The following query returns the single record:

```
SELECT [full name]
FROM myTable
WHERE [full name] LIKE '%LastName%'
```

However, the following query does not:

```
SELECT [full name]
FROM myTable
WHERE [full name] = 'Firstname Lastname'
```

I have verified the record exists, I have copied the value of the entity to make sure there was no funny business going on with the data. It comes up clean, I even tried this:

```
SELECT [full name]
FROM myTable
WHERE [full name] = 'Firstname Lastname '
```

to make sure there wasn't a random space at the end of the column. What would cause an issue like this?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer. `=` works only for an exact match. You clearly don't have an exact match. That is literally the most specific I can be without verifiable information.

Comment: Hi Devin, thanks for the quick response. I understand that I don't have an exact match. In this table I'm dealing solely with full names of people. So if you were Devin Burke, your name would appear as "Devin Burke" in the database. Simply a space between your first and last names.

Based on this, if I were to query my table with 

`Select [full name] 
From myTable
Where [full name] like '%Burke%'`

I would get the expected result, however, the following query (expecting the same result) returns an empty set.

`Select [full name]
from myTable
Where [full name] = 'Devin Burke'`

Comment: What is the result of SELECT [full name] FROM myTable WHERE [full name] LIKE '%LastName%'?

Comment: Then it's pretty obvious that these is not only a space between Firstname and Lastname, but other character(s) as well.

Comment: `SELECT [full name]
FROM myTable
WHERE [full name] LIKE %LastName%` Include few sample results of this query's o/p so as to debug where you are lacking any space or etc

Comment: Maybe you can try it with patterns like '%Firstname%Lastname%', '%F%L%', '%Firstname%', and so on, to try to isolate where the difference is?

Comment: Maybe there's a space before Firstname or after LastName.  What does `WHERE [full name] LIKE 'Firstname%Lastname'`.  If it still returns `NULL`, then there're characters before Firstname and/or after Lastname.

Comment: Thank you all for your constructive feedback! @Eric now it is painfully obvious that it might be something of that nature. When I'm back in the office I'll tackle this again. The different perspective is definitely refreshing. It is odd however, having copied the data straight from the SSMS result window into a text editor it appears perfectly normal, with only one space between the names and nothing wrapping.

Comment: what is that single record you got as o/p post that and your query will be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a handy script I use to identify invisible characters; it gives you every character in the string but as a separate row per character.

```
DECLARE @nstring NVARCHAR(1000)

select top 1 @nstring = [full name]
FROM myTable
WHERE [full name] LIKE '%LastName%'

print @nstring

DECLARE @position INT
 SET @position = 1

DECLARE @CharList TABLE (
 Position INT,
 UnicodeChar NVARCHAR(1),
 UnicodeValue INT
 )

WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@nstring)
 BEGIN
 INSERT @CharList
 SELECT @position as Position
 ,CONVERT(nchar(1),SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeChar
 ,UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeValue
 SET @position = @position + 1
 END

SELECT * FROM @CharList
```

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to spin this when I'm in front of this problem again

Comment: So I've ran the query, and the results revealed an empty character with unicode value '13' followed by 5 more rows with 'NULL' values, this means there are hidden characters trailing the end of the last name in question. 
This has essentially answered my question, thank you, Chris!

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator works only when it got exact match

but  The `LIKE` operator is used in a  to search for a specified pattern in of a data.

so in your case your compare value is not directly matched with the column values that's why it does not returned any rows but in times like it matched pattern so it returned rows

Comment: Would there be any explanation as to why it is unable to get an exact match? I've verified that the contents of the record only contain the text, and nothing else. "Michael Rodriguez" is how the name appears exactly in the database, but if I query with: `SELECT [full name] FROM myTable WHERE [full name] = 'Michael Rodriguez'` an empty set is returned.

Comment: @MRod93 may be space related issue is there though i suspect this

Comment: @MRod93 if possible crate your table and insert data https://dbfiddle.uk/ in fiddle and share with us

Comment: Just to check if it's a space issue: what is the result of `SELECT [full name] FROM myTable WHERE [full name] like '%Michael%Rodriguez%'`?

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` as the name itself suggests, is mainly used to compare data of some form that form is mostly `regular expressions`

whereas,

the `=` finds only the exact match not that it should be of some form rather the data on left of `=` should be a crystal clear copy of whats on the right of it.

Eg.

As per your above input sample
`..where fullname LIKE %FirstName%`. This would mean in general, select data  Where fullname has firstname in it

If I replace this `%` 
`...where fullname LIKE FirstName`
then it would be same as 
`...where fullname = FirstName` coz here it wants exact match not data of some form

Comment: Then there is something, perhaps invisible, inside the string causing the exact comparison to return an empty set

Comment: check your data by running that select query with `LIKE` and post few of those results in your query

Answer (score 0):

There is a tip given on [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4648/sql-server-bulk-insert-row-terminator-issues/) that says you can use SSIS.  The article also explains this issue occurring with the ROWTERMINATOR.  With that said, I would create an SSIS project that contains a package that does the bulk data insert from the data source.  If this is a repeated process it can be scheduled or quickly tested in the SSMS.

If you are new to SSIS or are not familiar with SSIS, refere here: [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)